# When did Canada get the rights reserved by the 1867 British North America Act?

Tags: britain, north-america

After becoming a country in 1867, Canada was not entirely independent. Britain retained 3 important powers: control of Canada’s defense, control of Canada’s foreign relations, and the requirement to send all laws passed by Canada’s Parliament to Britain for Royal Assent before they became actual laws.
Why Britain did this?
When and how Canada got these powers back?
Also explain how Royal Assent works, and why Canada was the only former British Colony to have this requirement to pass its own laws.

Supported link will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: The act is covered by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_Act,_1867); can you edit the question to specify what you need to know that is not already covered and in the [1931 Statue of Westminster?](https://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/statute-of-westminster#:~:text=On%2011%20December%201931%2C%20the,cemented%20the%20Dominions'%20legislative%20independence.)